# display label next to icon in Google Maps KML

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using KML with the Google Maps API.  The KML is used to display Mile Markers on interstates (see screenshot):

[image]

A snippet of the KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <Document>
      <Style id="randomLabelColor">
         <LabelStyle>
            <color>ff0000cc</color>
            <colorMode>random</colorMode>
            <scale>1.5</scale>
         </LabelStyle>
      </Style>
      <Placemark>
         <name>17</name>
         <styleUrl>#randomLabelColor</styleUrl>
         <description>I-684 MM NORTHBOUND: 17</description>
         <Style>
            <IconStyle>
               <Icon>
                  <href>http://www.xxxx.com/images/mapicons/milemarker.png</href>
               </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
         </Style>
         <Point>
            <coordinates>-73.67661,41.25393</coordinates>
         </Point>
      </Placemark>
   </Document>
</kml>
```

I realize clicking the Mile Marker icon will display a callout with the name and description.  But is it possible to have a label drawn on the map next to the icon?  I would like to put the numeric mile marker on the map (e.g. 17)

Or instead of KML do I need to use javascript and create markers?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to the same question. Going over the Google Maps API "KML and GeoRSS Layers" guide I noticed that the `<LabelStyle>` [element is not supported](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements).